# Instantiating a parent object throws an error

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm brushing up on Java and trying to figure out how Java manages inheritances. When I wrote these lines as follows, the message below is thrown,

```
class Foo {
 int a;

 public Foo(int a) {
     this.a = a;
     System.out.println(a);
 }

 public static void method() {
     System.out.println("Hello");
 }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Foo foo = new Foo(4);
 }
}
```

> ```
> Main.java:15: error: constructor Foo in class Foo cannot be applied to given types;
>     class Bar extends Foo {
>     ^
>  required: int
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> 1 error
> ```

As you can see, I'm instantiating from `Foo` class without passing through `Bar` subclass, but the error states the calling is not right. What is the reason this happens?

Now, if I add either a default constructor in Foo or a constructor in Bar, like this:

```
    class Bar extends Foo {
      public Bar(int a)  {
         super(a);
     }
    }
```

The program now works as intended.

If not dealing at any moment with any Bar objects in the main method, why should I write the implementation for a `Bar` constructor calling its superclass', or otherwise implement the default constructor for `Foo`? I find it so rare.

Comment: In short, by omitting the constructor in `Bar`, it would attempt to default it with `class Bar { public Bar() { super(); } }`. In effect, calling the zero-parameter constructor for `Foo`, which doesn't exist (since a non-zero arg constructor exists, it overrides the default/implicit zero-arg constructor), causes this error. By adding the constructor under Bar you've made explicit what a constructor for `Bar` should look like, and the error disappears as no default constructor needs to be generated

Comment: But, why is the compiler struggling with the Bar constructor if I'm not creating any objects of it?

Comment: Because it's uncompilable, in essence. Just like if you did `class Bar { svhjksaldngf; }`, the compiler would complain because it's nonsense, regardless of you using `Bar` or not. Notice the error points to the inside of the `Bar` class, not to your line in `#main`

Comment: Sorry, finally can get it. Thank so much you for your answer :D.

Comment: @Oblivion regarding the compiler struggling with the Bar constructor: please, note that if you create a Bar object, you're also implicitly creating a Foo object since the Bar inherits from Foo.

Comment: @bichoFlyer thanks for your answer! :D Now I can understand it more clearly.